# Desktop application for browsing and editing SQLite database files that works natively in Apple Silicon (M1)

Tags: sqlite, apple

I'm using a MacBook Pro with the M1 processor and I need a free desktop application for browsing and editing SQLite database files that works natively (without having to use Rosetta).

I have seen the following, but none of them work natively:

- [SQLite Studio](https://sqlitestudio.pl)
- [DB Browser for SQLite](https://sqlitebrowser.org)

Does anyone know if there is any application that works natively on Apple Silicon?

Comment: @Robert I am pleasantly surprised by this excellent application, which works great and has a very well done graphical interface. Many thanks. If you think it appropriate, put it as an answer so that it can serve other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out the "Universal Database Tool" [**DBeaver**](https://dbeaver.io/) Community Edition.

It supports SQLite and several other databases and on their [download page](https://dbeaver.io/download/) they provide an image for MacOS for M1/Silicon (dmg).

DBeaver is free and open-source (Apache License). It bases on Java.